# Magento 2 append custom attribute to product name

Tags: magento, magento2

I would like to add 2 custom attributes after the product name EVERYWHERE in the magento 2 shop.

Like "Productname Attribute1 Attribute2"

Is this possible and how? Do i need to modify every page or is there a way to act directly on the product name rendering for the whole system?

thanks

Comment: can you tell me how can you create custom attribute?

Comment: yes it is possible

Comment: now check my answer if you have difficult in it please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Fot that you have to create extension. Please check my code

1. Create folder in `app/code/Magenest`
2. Create sub folder in `app/code/Magenest/Sample`
3. Now create `registration.php` with following code

   ```
   <?php

    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
       \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
       'Magenest_Sample',
        __DIR__
   );
   ```
4. Create `etc` folder in `app/code/Magenest/Sample/`
5. Create `module.xml` in `etc` folder with following code

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
   <module name="Magenest_Sample" setup_version="2.0.0">    
   </module></config>
   ```
6. Create folder in `frontend` in `app/code/Magenest/Sample/etc/`
7. Create a file `di.xml` file in `app/code/Magenest/Sample/etc/frontend` with following code

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
   <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" type="Magenest\Sample\Model\Product"/>
   </config>
   ```
8. Now create a `Model` folder in `app/Magenest/Sample/`
9. Create `Product.php` in Model folder with following code

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Magenest\Sample\Model;
   class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
   {
   public function getName()
   {

   $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
   $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($this->_getData('entity_id'));
    $myattribute = $product->getResource()->getAttribute('putyourcustomattribute')->getFrontend()->getValue($product);

    $changeNamebyPreference = $this->_getData('name') . ' '. $myattribute;
    return $changeNamebyPreference;
    }
    }
   ```